# java ResultSet overwrite

Tags: java, sql, resultset, multiple-resultsets

I seem to be having some issues with my result sets I have named them differently but they both seem to have the same data in but I can't figure it out why.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM blog_comments;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int colNum = rsmd.getColumnCount();
boolean more = rs.next();

String query2 = "SELECT * FROM blog_entries;";
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(query2);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd2 = rs2.getMetaData();
int colNum2 = rsmd2.getColumnCount();
boolean more2 = rs2.next();
```

I have looked in debugging and they both have the same columns but i don't think they should have any suggestions.

Comment: you don't think or you are sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need a new Statement to instantiate your new ResultSet.

```
Statement st1 = Conn.CreateStatement();
Statement st2 = Conn.CreateStatement();

ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery();
ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery();
```

From [Statement API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

Comment: any particular reason for that?

Comment: From the Javadocs: "By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists."

Comment: yes that worked thanks for that I'll tick it as soon at the site lets me

Comment: @quoi sorry, i just had automatic reboot on my laptop, i will updatefrom the API .

Comment: @IanRoberts thanks for posting it as comment. i will include the APi link in my answer